# Cannot create ISO image of bootable CD-ROM: not Mode1

Tags: iso-image, compact-disc, bootable-media

When I try to create an ISO image of a bootable CD-ROM with [PlexTools Professional XL V3.16](http://www.plextor-digital.com/index.php/component/option,com_jdownloads/Itemid,55/catid,86/cid,470/task,view.download/), then I get an error message:

> Warning: the selected source is not Mode1. Only Mode1 tracks can be used for ISO images.

*Will it in general not be possible to create an ISO image off that CD-ROM, or is that a problem specific to the software that I'm using?*

[image: Screenshot of error dialog]

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and quickest way to figure it out is to try another software. Try [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/), its free and does not take much space on the disk.
(please don't consider this as advertising) You can chose any other software, I just recommended the one I know.

You can also read some info on the subject [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#Relation_to_CD-ROM_modes).

*UPDATE:

I found a very good [discussion](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/22285-are-these-2-formatsbin-and-img-suitable-for-making-images-for-all-kinds-of-discs/) that you might find useful. I think you might want to stick to using `*.BIN`. After all it is a standard format, so you really should not worry too much about it. Also I tend to believe that PlexTools that you were using also creates `*.BIN`,  and just gives it another extension.

Also the discussion links [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image#Limitations)

So, answering your original question: you might not be able to create `*.ISO` out of your CD if it has multiple tracks, however there is no problem with creating `*.BIN`, It will do the job just fine, it is not specific to ImgBurn and is as widely used as `*.ISO`. You will still be able to mount and/or burn it.

Comment: ImgBurn selects as filename for the image of that disk: `CD_ROM.BIN` *Is that not an ISO image? Is it an image data format specific to ImgBurn?* I am asking because: 1. With PlexTools I can copy the image in non-ISO format `.pxi`, which seems proprietary to Plextor. 2. For a standard data DVD, ImgBurn uses extension `.iso`, i.e. not `.bin`.

Comment: Not sure how this is relevant to your original question. But I will try to answer. Fristly, `*.bin` is not specific to ImgBurn. It is a raw binary image of your disk. Secondly, `*.bin` should be recognized by other programs and it can be mounted using usual mount tools (whatever you use). Also, there are converters that allow you to convert `*.bin` to `*.iso`. However I don't understand what exactly are you trying to achieve. Did ImgBurn do the job for you?

Comment: I would like to create an image in a *standardized* format, preferably ISO. Otherwise, I could just use PlexTools, because that allows creating an image, though in what seems to be a proprietary format. My original questions stands: *Will it in general not be possible to create an ISO image off that CD-ROM [...]?*

Comment: I have just installed ImgBurn specifically to look at that issue. Could you confirm which version of ImgBurn are you using and how exactly are you trying to create your `ISO` file?

Comment: I start ImgBurn 2.5.8.0 with a bootable CD-ROM in my drive. The destination by default is `CD_ROM.bin`. With a non-bootable data DVD, the default destination ends in `.iso`. (see above)

Comment: Ok, can you go into more details. I assume you switch to **Read mode** and then select your CD/DVD drive as source and some file as a destination. Do you get a dropdown menu with file type for destination? Because this is what I usually get. You can attach screenshots, that would be helpful

Comment: After opening ImgBurn, I click on *Create image file from disk*. In the screen that follows, you can see the destination file name that I'm talking about. It changes when I switch disks. (see above)

Comment: See update to my answer ^^